# Should I use Settings.System when writing our Android SDK for developers?

Tags: android, settings, system

We are not develping applications. Instead we provide a SDK for developers. One Service is used to do our job for all apps integrated our SDK, thus we have to save some "global settings".

I found `android.provider.Settings.System` is widely used in our project, which means we use `Settings.System.putString()` to save and `Settings.System.getSring()` to read. However, there are too few developers using this.

I am wondering if we shouldn't use this class, will Android forbidden us to use `Settings.System` in the next version? If is safe?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't forbidden, but they deprecate settings frequently.  Don't be surprised if you end up needing to write new code for the next version of Android.

Comment: Thank you. If there any better solution to solve my problem? Content Provider is not that good because we actually only need one copy of "global settings". If we use one Content Provider for each app, we have to do a lot of sync work.

Comment: BTW,what do you mean by "they deprecate settings frequently"? It works  in Android 2.x to 4.3

Comment: Look at the list of constants in that class.  Many of them deprecate with each new release.  Either they get moved to secure, or they go away as they decide not to allow public access.

Comment: Thanks, Gabe. I'm not using any of the  Constants in that class. It seems putString method is not deprecate.